# Incomplete GCLOUD SQL UPDATE operation upon STORAGE FULL is preventing any further operations including START

Tags: startup, diskspace

Stopped SQL service before realizing storage was full.
The UPDATE OPERATION during stopping did not cleanly complete.
Now any further operations, including START and attempting to change storage size give only the error:

"Operation failed because another operation was already in progress."

Tried from both web cloud console and gcloud command line. Same error on both.

How can I clear this incomplete UPDATE OPERATION so I can then increase storage size and start the SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution, but apparently the OPERATION does eventually complete after 2 to 3 hours. And this continues, every 2 to 3 hours, until an operation which increases the storage size, which again takes 2 to 3 hours to complete, and then the interface works normally again.

Posting this in case someone else runs into this same problem. There may still be a better solution, but giving it a lot of time does seem to work.